# Add undetermined number of AND on Linq-SQL Query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say that I have the following function...

```
private List<QueryObject> ReturnSQLData (DateTime d1, DateTime d2, string[] arrayOfNames)
{
    var results = (from a in _context.Names
                   where (a.CreatedOn >= d1 && a.CreatedOn <d2)

                   select new QueryObject
                   {
                       FirstName = a.Name
                       LastName = a.LastName
                   }).ToList();

    return results;
}
```

How could I continue create a Linq query where I have something line this?

```
private List<QueryObject> ReturnSQLData (DateTime d1, DateTime d2, string[] arrayOfNames)
{
    var results = (from a in _context.Names
                   where (a.CreatedOn >= d1 && a.CreatedOn <d2)
                   && (arrayOfNames[0].Equals("abc") || arrayOfNames[1].Equals("cde")
                   select new QueryObject
                   {
                       FirstName = a.Name
                       LastName = a.LastName
                   }).ToList();

    return results;
}
```

Note that I don't really know the size of the string[] until I am actually executing the code. How could I then add this statement on my linq query?

```
> && (arrayOfNames[0].Equals("abc") || arrayOfNames[1].Equals("cde") ||
> ... || arrayOfNames[n].Equals("cde"))
```

Would that be possible?

BTW. I am running this on a ASP.NET 5 MVC6 EF7 solution in case it helps :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you including the `arrayOfNames[0].Equals...` inside the `where` condition? It doesn't seem that these are related to the query. Couldn't you put them in an `if` statement before the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you do:

```
&& arrayOfNames.Contains("cde")
```

Comment: Would that evaluate each member of the array? I'll try it just in case :)

Comment: It really does work! Awesome! I never thought it could be that easy... thanks a million!